# Oracle set multiple system variables

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to set multiple system variables in a single command?

For e.g. set the below system variables in a single line?

```
SET COLSEP '    '
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET LINESIZE 10000
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
```

Checked http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699283 but don't see an example of doing so.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: Learned something new today!

Comment: I searched for ages for such a thing also and couldn't see any examples!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Is it possible to set multiple system variables in a single command?`

Yes you can. Simply specify variable name/value pairs using space as a delimiter between previous variable's new value and the next variable's name. Here is an example:

```
/* display variables' current values */
SQL> show colsep echo feedback heading linesize

colsep " "
echo OFF
FEEDBACK ON for 6 or more rows
heading ON
linesize 80

/* Assign new values */
SQL> set colsep "|" echo on echo on feedback off heading off linesize 1000;

/* Make sure changes are in effect */
SQL> show colsep echo feedback heading linesize

colsep "|"
echo ON
feedback OFF
heading OFF
linesize 1000


SQL> spool off;
```

**Note:** When number of system variables are more than a few, this approach will drastically reduce readability. So it would be better to dedicate each variable/value pair its own `SET` command.